# Build Fail when i add Ext js lib to my web application

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, sencha-cmd

I have created a Ext js 4.2.2 sample application using sencha cmd and I want to run using eclispe.When I copy the generated app in webcontent folder in my webapp build is getting failed and throwing eclispe is running out of memory .

Previously  I have worked with ext 4.0.7 where i had copied entire library directly into my webcontent folder without any building failure issues.

Kindly help me in these issue.

Comment: Edit eclipse.ini file and increase Xmx value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is not suitable for javascript validations. Sometimes it messes up with javascript and throws this kind of error. You can disable javascript validation to get rid-off this error.

Go to window-preferences, search for mark
Select Javascript - editor - Mark Occurrences
Uncheck Mark selected occurrences as shown below

Fore more info : http://www.balasblog.com/2014/03/an-internal-error-occurred-during.html